# Finding court cases involving some organization

Tags: legal-citation

How can I find court cases that involve a given organization (e.g. some company)?

Comment: In what country?

Comment: Trial court or appellate court? Knowing both the country and the likely state or county would help a lot. In the U.S. knowing if it was in state or federal court would likewise be crucial. In some places, the search tools exist but are unavailable to people who aren't lawyers or private investigators without a fair amount of inconvenience. No harm in trying Google to see if you can find it before doing a more complete search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I find court cases that involve a given organization (e.g.
>   some company)?

Based on other inquiries you have posted, I gather that you refer to the US.

A very useful, cost-free resource is [leagle.com](http://www.leagle.com/leaglesearch), where you can search for court opinions by court, party name, citation, and so forth.

Another free resource is https://www.justia.com/courts/ . To me it doesn't seem as flexible as Leagle from the standpoint of its search form, but maybe I just haven't explored it enough.

LexisNexis allows for more sophisticated search criteria. You would need a paid subscription unless you can access it from a public/county/community college. Learning the search commands & syntax is not hard. Although its sophisticated functionality is quite useful, I should mention that it not always fetches all the cases it should. LexisNexis was for a while the only resource I used for my legal research. But once I started using Leagle.com, I realized that LexisNexis was missing a case that was extremely important to my litigation.

The aforementioned sites only display court opinions. Many county courts have implemented systems such as Odyssey (example: see [here](https://cmspublic.3rdcc.org/default.aspx)), where you can search from home whether (and if so, the case history) an organization has sued or been sued in that court. To read the parties' briefs, motions, evidence, etc., you would need to go to the courthouse and request to see the case file.

[PACER](https://www.pacer.gov/) displays the contents of pleadings, motions, briefs, etc. filed in federal court. I am not sure whether there's a type of cost-free account or whether PACER starts charging after requesting the nth page or record.